# MYSQL group of auto numbering

Tags: mysql

I have some situation like:

Query:

```
set @rank = 0;
select @rank:=@rank+1, CONCAT_WS(" ",`Group`, SubGroup, TertiaryGroup) Items,ItemGroup, item from myTable
```

Here's my sample Text Data

**ITEMS:**

```
A. CARRIER: 1. UNDERCARRIAGE: 1.1 Track System Condition: 
A. CARRIER: 1. UNDERCARRIAGE: 1.1 Track System Condition: 
A. CARRIER: 1. UNDERCARRIAGE: 1.1 Track System Condition: 
A. CARRIER: 1. UNDERCARRIAGE: 1.1 Track System Condition: 
A. CARRIER: 1. UNDERCARRIAGE: 1.1 Track System Condition:   
A. CARRIER: 1. UNDERCARRIAGE: 1.1 Track System Condition:
A. CARRIER: 1. UNDERCARRIAGE: 1.1 Track System Condition:   
A. CARRIER: 1. UNDERCARRIAGE: 1.1 Track System Condition:       
A. CARRIER: 1. UNDERCARRIAGE: 1.1 Track System Condition:       
A. CARRIER: 1. UNDERCARRIAGE: 1.2 Final Drive System Condition:         
A. CARRIER: 1. UNDERCARRIAGE: 1.3 Transmission Condition: 
A. CARRIER: 1. UNDERCARRIAGE: 1.3 Transmission Condition: 
A. CARRIER: 1. UNDERCARRIAGE: 1.3 Transmission Condition:   
A. CARRIER: 1. UNDERCARRIAGE: 1.3 Transmission Condition: 
A. CARRIER: 1. UNDERCARRIAGE: 1.3 Transmission Condition: 
A. CARRIER: 1. UNDERCARRIAGE: 1.3 Transmission Condition:   
A. CARRIER: 1. UNDERCARRIAGE: 1.4 Underchassis Condition:       
A. CARRIER: 1. UNDERCARRIAGE: 1.4 Underchassis Condition:   
A. CARRIER: 1. UNDERCARRIAGE: 1.4 Underchassis Condition:   
B. ENGINE SYSTEM Condition:     
B. ENGINE SYSTEM Condition:         
B. ENGINE SYSTEM Condition:         
B. ENGINE SYSTEM Condition:         
B. ENGINE SYSTEM Condition:         
B. ENGINE SYSTEM Condition:         
B. ENGINE SYSTEM Condition:         
B. ENGINE SYSTEM Condition:         
B. ENGINE SYSTEM Condition:         
B. ENGINE SYSTEM Condition:         
B. ENGINE SYSTEM Condition:         
B. ENGINE SYSTEM Condition:
```

Only the items is enough for me thanks,

But i need a result that the auto numbering count back start to `1` if the items is different or changed.

Like from my sample image result the number 10 must back to `1` and the next should be back to `1,2,3,4` again and so on.

Only the `items` column not the `item`

Is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: would you like to add sample data as text to the question? Hint -order by and test for change.

Comment: Thanks @P.Salmon wait will update my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a way of ordering your data (such as an auto_increment id column) you can

```
insert into t (items)  values
('A. CARRIER: 1. UNDERCARRIAGE: 1.1 Track System Condition:'),
('A. CARRIER: 1. UNDERCARRIAGE: 1.1 Track System Condition:' )  ,
('A. CARRIER: 1. UNDERCARRIAGE: 1.1 Track System Condition:'),       
('A. CARRIER: 1. UNDERCARRIAGE: 1.1 Track System Condition:' ) ,    
('A. CARRIER: 1. UNDERCARRIAGE: 1.2 Final Drive System Condition:')  ,       
('A. CARRIER: 1. UNDERCARRIAGE: 1.3 Transmission Condition:'),
('A. CARRIER: 1. UNDERCARRIAGE: 1.3 Transmission Condition:' ),
('B. ENGINE SYSTEM Condition:') ,   
('B. ENGINE SYSTEM Condition:' ) ;

select items ,
            if(items <> @p,@rn:=1,@rn:=@rn+1) rn,
            @p:=items previousitem
from t
cross join (select @rn:=0,@p:='') r
order by id;

+-----------------------------------------------------------------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| items                                                           | rn   | previousitem                                                    |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| A. CARRIER: 1. UNDERCARRIAGE: 1.1 Track System Condition:       |    1 | A. CARRIER: 1. UNDERCARRIAGE: 1.1 Track System Condition:       |
| A. CARRIER: 1. UNDERCARRIAGE: 1.1 Track System Condition:       |    2 | A. CARRIER: 1. UNDERCARRIAGE: 1.1 Track System Condition:       |
| A. CARRIER: 1. UNDERCARRIAGE: 1.1 Track System Condition:       |    3 | A. CARRIER: 1. UNDERCARRIAGE: 1.1 Track System Condition:       |
| A. CARRIER: 1. UNDERCARRIAGE: 1.1 Track System Condition:       |    4 | A. CARRIER: 1. UNDERCARRIAGE: 1.1 Track System Condition:       |
| A. CARRIER: 1. UNDERCARRIAGE: 1.2 Final Drive System Condition: |    1 | A. CARRIER: 1. UNDERCARRIAGE: 1.2 Final Drive System Condition: |
| A. CARRIER: 1. UNDERCARRIAGE: 1.3 Transmission Condition:       |    1 | A. CARRIER: 1. UNDERCARRIAGE: 1.3 Transmission Condition:       |
| A. CARRIER: 1. UNDERCARRIAGE: 1.3 Transmission Condition:       |    2 | A. CARRIER: 1. UNDERCARRIAGE: 1.3 Transmission Condition:       |
| B. ENGINE SYSTEM Condition:                                     |    1 | B. ENGINE SYSTEM Condition:                                     |
| B. ENGINE SYSTEM Condition:                                     |    2 | B. ENGINE SYSTEM Condition:                                     |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks @ P.Salmon ill try this.

Comment: i got a result but  it returns 1
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
1
1
0
0
0
0
0
1
0
0
1
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
 in numbering. Its not incrementing

Comment: Sorry its my mistake for the rn, thanks so much its working well.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`` set @rank = 0;
set @key = '';
SELECT IF(
     CONCAT_WS(" ",`Group`, SubGroup, TertiaryGroup) = @key,
     @rank:=@rank+1,
     1
   ),
   @key:=CONCAT_WS(" ",`Group`, SubGroup, TertiaryGroup) Items,ItemGroup, item 
FROM myTable ``

Comment: Thanks for your answer, ill try this.